# Add and Delete fields dynamically jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am adding and deleting fields dynamically.
I am using jquery hide show to dynamically load new textarea or delete (hide)

I am aware of the append method as well by for loop but as I am doing this in wordpress where textrea = wp_editor so I can not use the append method and hence need to add static html and then use hide show.

I am able to achieve the dynamic adding of the fields as well as deleting fields dynamically.

The only issue am facing is On delete, I want that the add field should again appear.
In short eg: I have limit of 5 fields for 1 group as in fiddle I have shown 3 differrent groups each with a limit of 5.
SO for each group when I click on "Add More" there are total 5 fields visible for that group but If I delete any one of the field, total remains to be 4 with NO ADD MORE. SO, Is it possible to have ADD More again if a field is deleted so IN SHORT unless there are five fields in a group ADD MORE should be there.

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u73Ltvq/)
Here is the sample code

```
<div class="col_box">
        <div class="col_3">
            <div id="rwd11" class="txtara_cls">
                <div class="col_txt_lft">
                    <textarea class="result11">aaaa</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rwd12" class="txtara_cls" style="display:none;">
                <div class="col_txt_lft">
                    <textarea class="result12">bbbb</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col_del_rght">
                    <a href="#"  onclick="document.getElementById('rwd12').style.display='none';return false;" class="deleterwd" style="" title="Delete this reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Delete</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rwd13" class="txtara_cls" style="display:none;">
                <div class="col_txt_lft">
                    <textarea class="result13">cccc</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col_del_rght">
                    <a href="#"  onclick="document.getElementById('rwd13').style.display='none';return false;" class="deleterwd" style="" title="Delete this reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Delete</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rwd14" class="txtara_cls" style="display:none;">
                <div class="col_txt_lft">
                    <textarea class="result14">ddddd</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col_del_rght">
                    <a href="#"  onclick="document.getElementById('rwd14').style.display='none';return false;" class="deleterwd" style="" title="Delete this reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Delete</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rwd15" class="txtara_cls" style="display:none;">
                <div class="col_txt_lft">
                    <textarea class="result15">eeeee</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col_del_rght">
                    <a href="#"  onclick="document.getElementById('rwd15').style.display='none';return false;" class="deleterwd" style="" title="Delete this reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Delete</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="hide_11" class="add_extra">         
                <a id="hide_1_1" href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="addrwd" style="" title="Add reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Add More Results</a>
            </div>       
            <div id="hide_12" class="add_extra" style="display:none;">
                <a id="hide_1_2" href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="addrwd" style="" title="Add reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Add More Results</a>
            </div>       
            <div id="hide_13" class="add_extra" style="display:none;">
                <a id="hide_1_3" href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="addrwd" style="" title="Add reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Add More Results</a>
            </div>       
            <div id="hide_14" class="add_extra" style="display:none;">  
                <a id="hide_1_4" href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="addrwd" style="" title="Add reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Add More Results</a>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col_box">
        <div class="col_3">
            <div id="rwd21" class="txtara_cls">
                <div class="col_txt_lft">
                    <textarea class="result21">ffff</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rwd22" class="txtara_cls" style="display:none;">
                <div class="col_txt_lft">
                    <textarea class="result22">ggggg</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col_del_rght">
                    <a href="#"  onclick="document.getElementById('rwd22').style.display='none';return false;" class="deleterwd" style="" title="Delete this reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Delete</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rwd23" class="txtara_cls" style="display:none;">
                <div class="col_txt_lft">
                    <textarea class="result23">hhhhh</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col_del_rght">
                    <a href="#"  onclick="document.getElementById('rwd23').style.display='none';return false;" class="deleterwd" style="" title="Delete this reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Delete</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rwd24" class="txtara_cls" style="display:none;">
                <div class="col_txt_lft">
                    <textarea class="result24">iiiii</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col_del_rght">
                    <a href="#"  onclick="document.getElementById('rwd24').style.display='none';return false;" class="deleterwd" style="" title="Delete this reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Delete</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rwd25" class="txtara_cls" style="display:none;">
                <div class="col_txt_lft">
                    <textarea class="result25">jjjjj</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col_del_rght">
                    <a href="#"  onclick="document.getElementById('rwd25').style.display='none';return false;" class="deleterwd" style="" title="Delete this reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Delete</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="hide_21" class="add_extra">         
                <a id="hide_2_1" href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="addrwd" style="" title="Add reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Add More Results</a>
            </div>       
            <div id="hide_22" class="add_extra" style="display:none;">
                <a id="hide_2_2" href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="addrwd" style="" title="Add reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Add More Results</a>
            </div>       
            <div id="hide_23" class="add_extra" style="display:none;">
                <a id="hide_2_3" href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="addrwd" style="" title="Add reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Add More Results</a>
            </div>       
            <div id="hide_24" class="add_extra" style="display:none;">  
                <a id="hide_2_4" href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="addrwd" style="" title="Add reward"><span class="icon-trash icon"></span>Add More Results</a>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the JS part

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#hide_1_1').click(function() {
           jQuery('#rwd12').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#hide_11').css('display', 'none');
            jQuery('#hide_12').css('display', 'block');
        });
        jQuery('#hide_1_2').click(function() {
           jQuery('#rwd13').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#hide_12').css('display', 'none');
            jQuery('#hide_13').css('display', 'block');
        });
        jQuery('#hide_1_3').click(function() {
           jQuery('#rwd14').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#hide_13').css('display', 'none');
            jQuery('#hide_14').css('display', 'block');
        });
        jQuery('#hide_1_4').click(function() {
           jQuery('#rwd15').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#hide_14').css('display', 'none');
        });
        jQuery('#hide_2_1').click(function() {
           jQuery('#rwd22').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#hide_21').css('display', 'none');
            jQuery('#hide_22').css('display', 'block');
        });
        jQuery('#hide_2_2').click(function() {
           jQuery('#rwd23').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#hide_22').css('display', 'none');
            jQuery('#hide_23').css('display', 'block');
        });
        jQuery('#hide_2_3').click(function() {
           jQuery('#rwd24').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#hide_23').css('display', 'none');
            jQuery('#hide_24').css('display', 'block');
        });
        jQuery('#hide_2_4').click(function() {
           jQuery('#rwd25').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#hide_24').css('display', 'none');
        });

    });
```

Comment: You can ***massively*** reduce the amount of HTML and JS here by reusing your functions by using classes in your HTML and also by cloning and appending elements instead of hiding and showing pre-existing ones.

Comment: The issue I am facing is I need to show a WYSIWYG editor in wordpress if I try to instantiate it javascript , it doesnt ends up looking same
so rather than using that method I am trying to use simple php code (takes only a for loop) to generate this html
I tried alot to make it work but failed miserably

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form role="form" action="" method="POST">
      <label>Stuff</label>
       <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
          <div class="multi-fields">
            <div class="multi-field">
            <input type="text" name="stuff[]">
          <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
      </div>
   </div>
<button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
   </div>
  </form>

 <script>
 $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
   $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    $('.multi-field:first-child',  $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
});
 $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
        $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
  });
 });
</script>
```

This is demo for dynamically add and remove.It helps o solve this problem.

Comment: I am working on admin end and it allow certain set of html that I can use. can you please try once with above html